# Округлить цифру

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть такой код:

```
<input id="multiply" type="text" name="number" value="100"><span class="result">4365</span>

    <script>window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   const multiplyInput = document.querySelector('#multiply');
   const resultElements = document.querySelectorAll('.result');

   resultElements.forEach(item => {
      item.setAttribute('data-default-count', item.innerText);
   });

   const calcData = () => {
      resultElements.forEach(item => {
         item.innerText = item.getAttribute('data-default-count') * multiplyInput.value;
      });
   }

   calcData();

   multiplyInput.addEventListener('input', calcData)

})</script>
```

Его задача - умножать цифру из span на значение из input. Все работает, но не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы в результате выводилось округленное до ближайшей тысячи число. Например: вместо  436500 должно получиться 436000, или вместо 5369 - 5300. Причем округление всегда должно быть в меньшую сторону.

Comment: 5300 это до ближайшей сотни, а не тысячи. А так просто делите на 1000, приводите к целому типу и умножайте на 1000. И не "цифру", а "число". Цифра - это знак.

Comment: Через Math.floor(); наверное с условием что результат будет определённой длины. Типа 4 цифры, округление двух последних, а при 6 цифрах округление до трёх.